# Prove of disprove the two problems on sequences

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> Prove of disprove the following two problems on sequences
>
> (i) If $a_n\rightarrow l $ iff $a_n^2\rightarrow l^2 $ as  $n\rightarrow \infty $
>
> (ii) $a_n^2\rightarrow 0 $ iff $a_n\rightarrow 0 $ as  $n\rightarrow \infty $

Attempt: (i) To show if $a_n\rightarrow l $ then $a_n^2\rightarrow l^2 $ as  $n\rightarrow \infty $

As $\{a_n\}$ is convergent then it should be bounded. then $|an|<\eta$ for all $n$

As $\{a_n\}$ converges to $l$ then for given $\epsilon>0$, there exist a natural number $N$ such that
$$|a_n-l|<\frac{\epsilon}{\eta +l}~~\forall n\geq N$$

Then  $$|a_n^2-l^2|=|(a_n-l)(a_n+l)|<\frac{\epsilon}{\eta +l} .(\eta +l)<\epsilon~~\forall n\geq N$$
Then $a_n^2\rightarrow l^2 $

**But the problem is $l$ may be +ve or -ve then the type of adjustment that I have done in $|a_n-l|<\frac{\epsilon}{\eta +l}~~\forall n\geq N$ is meaningful? Or some new condition like ($\eta+l>0$) is needed there. Please correct my proof.**

Please help me to prove (or disprove) the others.

Comment: Should we assume the multiplicative and divisive properties of limits?

Comment: Slip, you mean $|a_n|\lt \eta$ for some $\eta$. Then you want to use $\eta+|l|+1$, not $\eta+l$.  This is because $|a_n+l|\le \eta+|l|$. That will take care of your worries about negatives. The $+1$ is to take care of the (silly) possibility that $\eta=0$ and $l=0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks. Another problem is in $|a_n-l|<\frac{\epsilon}{\eta +l}~~\forall n\geq N$ if we take $l<0$ such that $\eta+l<0$, then $|a_n-l|<\frac{\epsilon}{\eta +l}~~\forall n\geq N$ becomes meaningless. What to do with this? Or instead I take  $|a_n-l|<\frac{\epsilon}{\eta +|l|}~~\forall n\geq N$

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, pick $N$ such that if $n\ge N$ then $|a_n-l|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{\eta+|l|+1}$. Note that this is for proving if $a_n\to l$ then $a_n^2\to l^2$. The other direction, as has been pointed out, is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(i)
The forward direction is correct as $x^2$ is continuous but the backward direction is not.
Let $a_n=-1$, we have $a_n^2 \to 1^2$ but clearly $a_n$ doesn't converge to 1.

(ii) Suppose we have $a_n^2 \to 0$.
This implies that $ \forall \epsilon >0, \exists N_{\epsilon }>0$ such that $n>N \implies |a_n^2|=|a_n|^2 \leq \epsilon^2$ which implies that $|a_n| \leq \epsilon$.

Conversely, if $a_n \to 0$. This implies that  $ \forall \epsilon >0, \exists N_{\epsilon }>0$ such that $n>N \implies |a_n| \leq \sqrt{\epsilon}$ which implies that $|a_n|^2=|a_n^2| \leq \epsilon$.

Comment: @Sing I think your first example is not completely accurate, as you can always say that $\;a_n^2=(-1)^2\to 1\;$ and **also** $\;a_n=-1\to -1\;$ and thus the condition is fulfilled...

Comment: hmm... I interpret the statement "$a_n^2 \to l^2 \implies a_n \to l$ as for any sequence $a_n and l$ that satisfy $a_n^2 \to l^2$, we can conclude that  $a_n \to l$. In this case, if I pick my $a_n=-1$ and $l=-1$, I might not see a problem with it. But I can't conclude that the statement is correct, there might be other combination that makes it a wrong statement. We look around and consider picking $a_n=-1$ and $l=1$ and we realized that hmm... the statement is not true for all such choice of $a_n$ and $l$ that satisfies $a_n^2 \to l^2$ after all.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is wrong. Take $a_n = \dfrac{-n}{n+2}$. You see that $a_n \to -1$, but $a_n^2 \to 1$. In this example, $a_n^2 \to 1 = (1)^2 $ does not imply $a_n \to 1$.

Comment: Yes. So? I don't see how that contradicts.

Comment: @Kf-Sansoo $a_n^2\to(-1)^2$ which is what the question is stating.

Answer (score 1):

1) You state $\;a_n\to\ell\iff a_n^2\to \ell^2\;$. This is false, since with

$$a_n:=(-1)^n\;,\;\;\text{we get that}\;\;a_n^2=(-1)^{2n}=1\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1=1^2\;,\;\text{yet}\;\;\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$$

doesn't even exist, so the direction $\;\Longleftarrow\;$ is false.

(2) is true.